# How to make sure a loop within a task has run at least once

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading, task

Let's say I have a class called `Scheduler` that contains a `Dictionary` of `<UserId, Task>`, the Task continuously loops and updates an internal Dictionary with Schedules for that User `<UserId, Schedule>` with information from a database i.e. I want to keep the information updated in real time.

I want to have a method on the `Scheduler` class `GetScheduleForUser` which checks to see if there is a Task for that User and if not it'll create the task wait til it finishes and then retrieves the `Schedules` for that User (lazy load it).

My question is, after the first iteration of the task I'll have a schedule available and I can just retrieve the schedule...no problem but for the first iteration I need to wait until the task is finished at least one time before retrieving the schedule.

I can just start the task and create a while loop until a certain flag is set when it's finished for the first time loop but it seems to me like there is a better way and it'll only be useful for the first iteration. Afterwards the schedule will always be available and I won't need the functionality.

Does anyone have a clean way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can use one of synchronization primitives like `TaskCompletionSource, SemaphoreSlim, ManualResetEventSlim, Mutex` etc..

Comment: I was thinking of doing that. The problem is I'll be resetting the manual event every time even though I really only need it the first time to make sure I have all the data

Comment: Take a look at using `Lazy` and `ConcurrentDictionary`: https://blogs.endjin.com/2015/10/using-lazy-and-concurrentdictionary-to-ensure-a-thread-safe-run-once-lazy-loaded-collection/

Comment: This design is not work anyway if you have more than one threads on your pool to run, the webgarden style... and if you can not control that, then you have problem.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I can think of would use `TaskCompletionSource`, which Eser mentioned in his comment. Here's a rough code sample with lots of console output to make it easier to follow what it's doing. I also added `IDisposable` to the Scheduler calss and a dictionary of `CancellationTokenSource` so that, when you're done with the Scheduler, it can stop all of the Tasks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    // Helper property to simplify console output
    public static string TimeString { get { return DateTime.Now.ToString("mm:ss.fff"); } }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var scheduler = new Scheduler())
        {
            var userID = "1";

            Console.WriteLine(TimeString + " Main: Getting schedule for first time...");
            var sched1 = scheduler.GetScheduleForUser(userID);
            Console.WriteLine(TimeString + " Main: Got schedule: " + sched1);

            Console.WriteLine(TimeString + " Main: Waiting 2 seconds...");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

            Console.WriteLine(TimeString + " Main: Getting schedule for second time...");
            var sched2 = scheduler.GetScheduleForUser(userID);
            Console.WriteLine(TimeString + " Main: Got schedule: " + sched2);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to end . . .");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Scheduler : IDisposable
{
    // Helper property to simplify console output
    public static string TimeString { get { return DateTime.Now.ToString("mm:ss.fff"); } }

    private Dictionary<string, Task> TasksDictionary { get; set; }
    private Dictionary<string, TaskCompletionSource<bool>> TaskCompletionSourcesDictionary { get; set; }
    private Dictionary<string, CancellationTokenSource> CancellationTokenSourcesDictionary { get; set; }
    private Dictionary<string, string> SchedulesDictionary { get; set; }

    public Scheduler()
    {
        TasksDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Task>();
        TaskCompletionSourcesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, TaskCompletionSource<bool>>();
        CancellationTokenSourcesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, CancellationTokenSource>();
        SchedulesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (TasksDictionary != null)
        {
            if (CancellationTokenSourcesDictionary != null)
            {
                foreach (var tokenSource in CancellationTokenSourcesDictionary.Values)
                    tokenSource.Cancel();

                Task.WaitAll(TasksDictionary.Values.ToArray(), 10000);

                CancellationTokenSourcesDictionary = null;
            }

            TasksDictionary = null;
        }

        CancellationTokenSourcesDictionary = null;
        SchedulesDictionary = null;
    }

    public string GetScheduleForUser(string userID)
    {
        // There's already a schedule, so get it
        if (SchedulesDictionary.ContainsKey(userID))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(TimeString + "     GetSchedule: Already had schedule for user " + userID);
            return SchedulesDictionary[userID];
        }

        // If there's no task yet, start one
        if (!TasksDictionary.ContainsKey(userID))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(TimeString + "     GetSchedule: Starting task for user " + userID);
            var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var token = tokenSource.Token;
            TaskCompletionSourcesDictionary.Add(userID, new TaskCompletionSource<bool>());
            var task = (new TaskFactory()).StartNew(() => GenerateSchedule(userID, token, TaskCompletionSourcesDictionary[userID]), token);
            TasksDictionary.Add(userID, task);
            CancellationTokenSourcesDictionary.Add(userID, tokenSource);
            Console.WriteLine(TimeString + "     GetSchedule: Started task for user " + userID);
        }

        // If there's a task running, wait for it
        Console.WriteLine(TimeString + "     GetSchedule: Waiting for first run to complete for user " + userID);
        var temp = TaskCompletionSourcesDictionary[userID].Task.Result;
        Console.WriteLine(TimeString + "     GetSchedule: First run complete for user " + userID);

        return SchedulesDictionary.ContainsKey(userID) ? SchedulesDictionary[userID] : "null";
    }

    private void GenerateSchedule(string userID, CancellationToken token, TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(TimeString + "         Task: Starting task for userID " + userID);

        bool firstRun = true;
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // Simulate work while building schedule
            if (token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(1000))
                break;

            // Update schedule
            SchedulesDictionary[userID] = "Schedule set at " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
            Console.WriteLine(TimeString + "         Task: Updated schedule for userID " + userID);

            // If this was the first run, set the result for the TaskCompletionSource
            if (firstRun)
            {
                tcs.SetResult(true);
                firstRun = false;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(TimeString + "         Task: Ended task for userID " + userID);
    }
}
```

Here's a fiddle to show it in action: [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OZJsft)